# Is there a function to partition an integer set?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

First I give an example. For an integer set $(0,1,2,3,4)$, there are eight kinds of subdivision or partition like this
$$(0,4);\\~~(0,1)(1,4);~~(0,2)(2,4);~~(0,3)(3,4);\\
(0,1)(1,2)(2,4);~~(0,1)(1,3)(3,4);~~(0,2)(2,3)(3,4);~~\\(0,1)(1,2)(2,3)(3,4); $$

For a more general set $(0,1,2,...,n)$, there are $2^{n-1}$ kinds of partition.I believe that there must be a special name for this kind of partition mathematically. How can I realize it in MMA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`P[n]` will return the set you are asking

```
P[n_] := Partition[Join[{0}, #, {n}], 2, 1] & /@ Subsets[Range[n - 1]]

P[4]
```

> {{{0, 4}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 4}}, {{0, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{0, 
>      1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{0, 2}, {2, 3}, {3,
>       4}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}}

Comment: Thanks, it works well!!!

Comment: @user10709 I'm glad I helped!

Comment: Of course, you can combine the functions so that only one application of `Map[]` is needed: `Partition[Join[{0}, #, {n}], 2, 1] & /@ Subsets[Range[n - 1]]`.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive yes, you are right